# How to build the multi-tenant SaaS Chat application using Node + Mysql+ Sequelize with best approach

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, multi-tenant

I am trying to build SaaS based chat application using NodeJS, SequelizeJs, ExpressJS, Mysql. I want to know best approach.
I able to connect with multiple databases using sequlizeJS.
But issue is that I am not sure that is this best approach or not?

**Scenario:**
When we start node server using pm2 or `node app.js` then Sequelize will create instance per client and loads the models for each database which will consume cpu and memory. Suppose there will be 10000 clients then does sequelize consume more memory?

3) Does it will slow the chat application?

4) If new client comes. So I have to create new database for him. It needs to restart node server to take effect newly created db instance. But my other clients gets affected with this restart. So how to handle new clients dynamically?

5) Is NodeJS, Sequelizejs, Mysql good choice for Saas based chat application?

Am I missing something in sequelize? Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Have you gone anyware with it, did you build it, do you have any advises?

Comment: @AnasBakro Yes. I have resolved this issue myself. I have used PostgreSQL instead of MySQL as PostgreSQL have schema. I used per schema for per tenant. I have used public schema as a master database. Flow of application is use public schema for authentication and authorization of tenant then generate JWT token and connect to his schema. Now it is working very well. No slowness, No downtime till yet.